# Error 500 Internal server error host google cloud

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform

Hola tengo un problema con mi blog, cuando abro la pagina con mi nombre de dominio (*www.aprendiendodeartesdigitales.com*) solo me aparece en la pantalla lo siguiente:

> "Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Pero cuando lo abro con la *ip externa*(http://130.211.112.9/) no tengo problema para visualizar el contenido alguien sabe a que se debe dicho error?

En lo que he investigado dice que el motivo puede ser el archivo **.htaccess** pero no lo puedo encontrar por ningún lado con *Filezilla*.

**Nota:** El *hosting* que estoy utilizando es con *Google Cloud Platform.*

Gracias espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: `.htaccess` suele estar en el directorio root, es decir, donde se encuentran los archivos de tu wordpress como `wp-config.php`. En los hostings tradicionales el directorio root del sitio se suele llamar `public_html`, en Google Cloud no sé si sea igual. El error 500 puede deberse también a problemas de memoria en el servidor o a otras causas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde el CMD, haciendo un comando `ping Aprendiendodeartesdigitales.com` obtengo una IP diferente a la que mencionas, dicho en resúmen:

El problema:

```
Aprendiendodeartesdigitales.com 
66.96.161.163
```

La solución:

En el panel de dominio, actualizar el record de tipo A que apunte hacia 130.211.112.9 en vez de 66.96.161.163

Esto puede tomar cierto tiempo para que los registros DNS se actualicen, paciencia y buen humor :D

Comment: Hola fredyfx ya hice lo del comando ping y en efecto tienes toda la razon pero sabes por que esta pasando? ya cheque el record A y apunta hacia 130.211.112.9  sabes que puede estar pasando?

Comment: y muchas gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: ¿Has actualizado a tu proveedor de dominios? Ten en cuenta que es diferente de actualizarlo en local :D

Comment: Tengo un provedor de dominio ajeno a mi provedor de host. Antes funcionaba muy bien la pagina con todo y el dominio pero tube que eliminar todo el blog y volverlo a hacer y la pagina funciona pero tengo ese problema con el dominio revise el dns y todo parece en orden. Gracias por seguir contestando.

Comment: de nada, ¿De casualidad los DNS del dominio fueron modificados? Si anda todo by default debería funcionar rápidamente :D

Comment: Del dominio solo la primera vez antes de que hiciera todo de nuevo y si funcionaba. Que me recomiendas que haga?

Comment: en el panel del dominio guarda un backup de todas las configuraciones, (dale pantallazos si gustas) resetea todo a default y procede a guardar los registros tipo A con el dominio nuevo :D

Comment: Gracias lo intentare si no funciona ya estaré de regreso por aquí jajaja mil gracias.